# My state property blowing up when editing state props in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I used Class Components for some reason, Im rendering the data got from input fields from the form to a table ,There are two components btw.

The output is like ,
[image: The Browser Output]

You can see there is two option Edit and Delete,on pressing Edit button the input field will be handled to edit and We want to Update the state on every Change in the Input field (onChange).Ive implemented the Delete feature by filter method.

The App.js file is,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    names: [
      /*
        Object structure
          {id: 1,name:'Aashiq'}
      */
    ],
    disable: true,
  };

  handleNameChange(e) {
    this.setState(
      {
        names: { ...this.state.names, name: e.target.value },
      },
      console.log(this.state.names)
    );
  }

  handleEdit() {
    this.setState({ disable: !this.state.disable }, () => {
      return console.log("%c Ready for editing", "background: #222;color:red");
    });
  }

  getButtonName() {
    return this.state.disable ? "Edit" : "Submit";
  }

  handleEditChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      names: [{ ...this.state.names, name: e.target.value }],
    });
  };

  renderTable() {
    return this.state.names
      .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
      .map((eachName) => {
        const { id, name } = eachName;
        return (
          <tr key={id}>
            <td>{id}</td>
            <td>
              <input
                value={name}
                disabled={this.state.disable}
                onChange={this.handleEditChange}
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="button"
                value={this.getButtonName()}
                onClick={(e) => this.handleEdit(e)}
              />

              <input
                type="button"
                value="Delete"
                onClick={() => this.deleteName(id)}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      });
  }

  deleteName = (id) => {
    this.state.names &&
      this.setState({
        names: this.state.names.filter((name) => name.id !== id),
      });
  };

  addName = (newName) => {
    this.setState((currentState) => {
      const newNames = [...currentState.names];
      newNames.push(newName);
      return {
        names: newNames,
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Form onSubmit={this.addName} names={this.state.names} />
        <br />
        <table id="details">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Names</th>
              <th>Operation</th>
            </tr>
            {this.renderTable()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

The form.js file is,

```
import React, { createRef } from "react";

export default function Form(props) {
  const nameInputRef = createRef();
  const idInputRef = createRef();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleChangeAndValidate();
  };

  const handleChangeAndValidate = () => {
    const { onSubmit, names } = props;
    const submittedName = nameInputRef.current.value;
    const submittedId = idInputRef.current.value;

    const hasDuplicates = names.find((name) => name.id === submittedId);
    if (hasDuplicates !== undefined) {
      alert("Enter unique id");
      idInputRef.current.focus();
    } else {
      onSubmit({ id: submittedId, name: submittedName });
      idInputRef.current.value = "";
      nameInputRef.current.value = "";
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="myform">
      <label style={{ fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        Name: {""}
        <input type="text" required ref={nameInputRef} />
      </label>{" "}
      <label style={{ fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        ID: {""}
        <input type="number" required ref={idInputRef} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

You can see,ive used functional component here and Ref.

You can see in the Ive used input box inside the  on editing the data should get updated in the state which of that structure,but While updating the name ,i.e On editing ...The id getting blown up,may be im using the wrong setstate() implementation here,Can some please correct this up,Thanks in advance!

[UPDATE]This is the [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/inserting-only-uniqe-id-forked-bwy8w?file=/src/App.js)

It will be a huge favour if someone fixes up and update! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not adding id in the `addName` method, where is the id?

Comment: @Prateek   Id comes from another components form.js

Comment: Yes, but where are you adding `id` to the state? I didn't seem to catch any.

Comment: @PrateekThapa ,Ive edited the question by including the other file too,please go through,Your feedback is more important

Answer (score 1):

The state is not updated correctly. You need to pass the id to identify the correct item:

```
 handleEditChange = (e, id) => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    this.setState((prev )=> {
       const item =  prev.names.find(i=> i.id === id);
       item.name = value;
       return {names: [...prev.names]};
    });
  };

      <input
        value={name}
        disabled={this.state.disable}
        onChange={()=> this.handleEditChange(e, id)}
      />
```

Comment: First thank you for answering, Can i know why using callback in setstate,what if using normal one!

Comment: You can pass the value directly, or use callback function where you can get the previous state value. Here you can find more info about setState, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Ok cool,the answer you've givn throws error as find() is not a function,i also edited the question ,included the other file, Form.js , can you please go through and edit your answer according to it .Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its right ,but can you explain the return statement,

return {names: [...prev.names]}

You are just spreading the previous state name not the item

Comment: Objects are mutable in JavaScript, when I get the item, this action does not create new object, it still keep the reference to de array item, this reference points to the object’s memory location, that is why any item modification will reflect in the array item

Comment: Is this correct , return {names: [...prev.names,item.name]} where I included the updated item.name with in my state,which is a array of objects

Comment: This return {names: [...prev.names,item.name]} will add new item to the array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222345/discussion-between-aashiq-ahmed-and-lissettdm).

Comment: It throws the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null,in the line,       item.name = e.target.value; https://codesandbox.io/s/inserting-only-uniqe-id-forked-bwy8w?file=/src/App.js, this is the working codesandbox link except for that error